# Find number of days to a certain value in R

Tags: r, time-series

Ok so I have a daily time series dataset spanning 30 years. What I was to do is to calculate the number of days from the start of each month until a threshold if reached using R.

For the sake of simplicity say it was for rainfall data as per the example below:

```
Date          Rainfall
01/01/1980    0
02/01/1980    0
03/01/1980    0
04/01/1980    0
05/01/1980    0
06/01/1980    0.2
07/01/1980    0.4
08/01/1980    0
09/01/1980    0
10/01/1980    0
11/01/1980    0
12/01/1980    0
13/01/1980    3.2
14/01/1980    0
15/01/1980    0
16/01/1980    0
...           ...
```

If I set the threshold to 1 in this data example the number of days until threshold is reached would be 13 days.

Does anyone have any idea about how this could be done in R so that I can calculate the average number of days until rainfall per month i.e. average for January over the 30 years etc.

Please let me know if you require a little bit of test data.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DF <- read.table(text="Date          Rainfall
01/01/1980    0
02/01/1980    0
03/01/1980    0
04/01/1980    0
05/01/1980    0
06/01/1980    0.2
07/01/1980    0.4
08/01/1980    0
09/01/1980    0
10/01/1980    0
11/01/1980    0
12/01/1980    0
13/01/1980    3.2
14/01/1980    0
15/01/1980    0
16/01/1980    0", header=TRUE)

DF$Date <- as.Date(DF$Date, format="%d/%m/%Y")
DF$months <- cut(DF$Date, "month")

thresh <- 1

library(plyr)
#use ddply or one of the many alternatives for split-apply-combine
ddply(DF, .(months), summarise, 
      reached =  
        #first TRUE
        which.max(
         #cumulative sum reached threshold?
         cumsum(Rainfall) >= thresh))

#      months reached
#1 1980-01-01      13
```

**Edit:**

This deals with the edge case of the threshold not being reached:

```
ddply(DF, .(months), summarise, 
      reached =  
        if (any(cumsum(Rainfall)>= thresh)) {
        which.max(
           cumsum(Rainfall) >= thresh)
        } else NA)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The code works perfectly when the threshold is met within a month but seems to be throwing up a really high number when it's not met (even higher than the number of days to when the threshold is met in the next month).

Comment: That's an edge case that is easy to catch.

Comment: You'll have to forgive me please I'm still a relative novice at this. What do you mean by edge cases? I've just done a few searches and am non the wiser! Thank you.

Comment: See my edit. However, we are not here to spoon-feed polished solutions to you. The idea is that you amend the code to your specific needs.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I realise that solutions should not be spoon fed. When I searched for 'edge cases' a lot of the information I got back wasn't clear and I wasn't sure about what was explicitly meant by this. So I was just wanting a bit of clarity and not necessarily a spoon fed answer. I assure you that I always try to look thoroughly for solutions before posting a question. I appreciate the time and effort you have taken to help me.